Listen to inner childs events in ReactJs
How can I listen to an event that occurs in a child of child of child... component?
In the example bellow, how can I handle to the "ChildLevel2 - button - onClick" event in the "MainComponent" ?
function MainComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <ChildLevel1/>
    </>
  );
}

function ChildLevel1() {
  return (
    <>
      <ChildLevel2/>
    </>
  );
}

function ChildLevel2() {
  return (
    <>
      <button>Click-me!</button>
    </>
  );
}


keep passing down prop or use context api or redux

you can create an onClick function inside the Main component, and pass it to ChildLevel2 as props.

@Tony, you mean  Main -> ChildLevel1 -> ChildLevel2 ?

Here are some possible ways
1. Passing down the function as a prop - This can be a headache if you have to pass it down too deep. Just 2 levels is just fine I guess


function MainComponent(){
  const handleButtonClick = (data) => {
    console.log('from child2', data);
  };
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildLevel1 onButtonClick={handleButtonClick}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

function ChildLevel1({onButtonClick}){
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildLevel2 onButtonClick={onButtonClick}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

};

function ChildLevel2({onButtonClick}){
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => onButtonClick('passed data')}>Click-me!</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainComponent />, document.getElementById("app"));
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>



2. Using Context API. createContext , useContext. Like a centralized state so works better if too deeply nested you won't have to keep passing as props


const ButtonClickContext = React.createContext(null);

function MainComponent(){
  const handleButtonClick = (data) => {
    console.log('from child2', data);
  };
  
  return (
    <ButtonClickContext.Provider value={handleButtonClick}>
      <React.Fragment>
        <ChildLevel1/>
      </React.Fragment>
    </ButtonClickContext.Provider>
  );
};

function ChildLevel1(){
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildLevel2/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

};

function ChildLevel2(){
  const onButtonClick = React.useContext(ButtonClickContext);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => onButtonClick('passed data')}>Click-me!</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainComponent />, document.getElementById("app"));
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>




to show an example of what the comments suggest:
const MainComponent = () => {
    const handleNestedEvent = (e) => {
        console.log('handling event in top level component', e);
    }
    return (
        <ChildLevel1 onNestedEvent={handleNestedEvent}/>
    )
}
const ChildLevel1 = ({ onNestedEvent }) => {
    return <ChildLevel2 onNestedEvent={onNestedEvent}/>
}
const ChildLevel2 = ({ onNestedEvent }) => {
    return <button onClick={onNestedEvent}>Click Me</button>
}

could instead useContext: react context docs
or redux: react redux docs
